# Flash and Localhost environment. No connection to the real web?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, connection, localhost, local

I'm developing a flash thingy that connects to the youtube api. The website that contains the flashthingy is developed locally on my computer.

I don't konw why flash does this, but it doesn't connect to anything on the real web. E.g. the youtube api. As soon as I deploy the project to a real server everything works fine.

Since I have a lot of dev still before me I'd love to test this stuff locally. Any idea what I have to do in order to get flash connected to real websites?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using the flash player content debugger? if not, you should download it from http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html.

Comment: the flash player debugger is a standalone player. not in the browser. I have the problem inside of the browser, that flash doesn't connect to anything outside my localhost stuff.

Comment: There is a debug version of the browser plugin too, on the page Taurayi links to. It can give you error messages with more info than the regular Flash Player plugin.

Comment: @mathiregister O_O are you sure? If you go to that link I sent you, theres a link that says "Download the Windows Flash Player 10.3 ActiveX control content debugger (for IE)" and "Download the Windows Flash Player 10.3 Plugin content debugger (for Netscape-compatible browsers)". Also I'm pretty sure that I have been using flash player content debugger for my browswer for a while now. I'm almost 100% certain that I have it because when I right-click flash content on a website and open the context menu, one of the context menu items reads "Debugger", but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All this is happening because of flash security sandbox.

go here:
http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

and add your root development directory to trusted sites.

for example: `D:/dev` Then it will be working fine.

if you have more folders, then add them too.

p.s. of if you are using a newer version of flash player just open flash in browser and click right mouse button, then Global Settings...

**UPDATE**

This is how it looks from my localFiles in the browser:

- first call is made by HTML to download ge_flash_player.gif image
- second call is made from flash to googleAnalytics, which as you can see Resulted a HttpStatus 200.

[image]

Comment: I too thought this was the problem hence why I suggested he download the flash player content debugger to see what kind of `SecurityError` he got.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a Flash executed locally in your browser (`file://C:/myflash.html`) connect to the Internet. You have to install a local server (WAMP, EasyPhp...) and run your Flash on `http://localhost`.

Comment: i do! it doesn't connect to real websites. My flash script connects to the youtube player api. However not in when i call it in my `http://localhost`... just on the real server!

Comment: can you use a sniffer to catch your flash's requests? http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ And as @Taurayi says, you should get the flash debugger _plugin_