# jPlayer does not work in IE9

Tags: html, jplayer

I use the [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org) plugin to playback videos on a site. It works fine in all browsers except of IE9. Is anybody aware of a way to force IE9 a fallback to the Flash solution instead of HTML5?

Thanks.

Comment: Se answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786034/how-play-flv-files-using-jplayer/17323745#17323745

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [solution](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-option-solution) option?

Answer (score 1):

Put this line of code at the very beginning of your document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

It forces IE9 to work under standard document mode.
Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ff468705

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I tried to setup Jplayer in a ASP.NET Web Forms project.
I saw that when I run the project on localhost, Flash PLayer don't let me execute it. I need to publish the project on a another IP to see it running.
My code was it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            ready: function () {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    flv: "<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/videos/myvideo.flv")%>"
                }).jPlayer("play");
            },
            solution: "flash,html",
            supplied: "flv",
            swfPath: "<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery_jplayer")%>",
            size: {
                width: "480px",
                height: "270px"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are developing on localhost or not, but as OG Brasil mentioned above, if you are developing on your home network (ie. localhost), flash doesn't seem to work on ie9.

To fix this on a windows7 computer go to **control panel >>> System and security >>> Flash player**
Then go to **advanced**. Under developer tools select **Trusted Location Settings**
Then add the path to your website. In my case it was on hard drive Z under wamp folder, so i added **z:\wamp**

This answer helped me  [Flash and Localhost environment. No connection to the real web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829004/flash-and-localhost-environment-no-connection-to-the-real-web)